# How to pass two objects data in a PUT request?

Tags: python, http, request, python-requests

I have the method below writen in Delphi:

`function acceptPutNF(const aJSONObject: TJSONObject; const aJSONArray: TJSONArray): TJSONObject;`

I'm trying to send a PUT request, but I don't know how to specify the second parameter/object data `aJSONArray` with python. I tried this:

```
nfe = {'CodigoUsuario':1,'CodigoEmpresa':1,'Originario':'1','CodigoCliente':1,'CodigoTransportador':1,'NaturezaOperacao':'1',
        'IndicadorPagamento':'1','ValorFrete':1,'ValorSeguro':1,'ValorOutrasDespesas':1,'ValorProdutosServicos':1,'ValorDescontoGlobal':1,'nformacoesContr':None}
nfe_itens = [{'CodigoProduto':1,'CodigoGradeProduto':1,'Quantidade':1,'ValorUnitario':1,'DescontoUnitario':1}]               

nfe_encoded = json.dumps(nfe)
nfe_itens_encoded = json.dumps(nfe_itens)

print nfe_encoded

url = 'http://localhost:88/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods/PutNF'
r = requests.put(url, data={nfe_encoded, nfe_itens_encoded})
```

I get an error message in the last instruction...

Comment: Can you add the error message?

Comment: I think it's related to passing an argument followed by a keyword argument, but I'm still learning Python as well

Comment: @JasonSperske: no, you are passing in a *set*, not a dictionary there.

Comment: Error: `File "C:\Program Files\eclipse-workspace\test\src\FirstModule.py", line 50, in <module>
    r2 = requests.put(url2, data={nfe_encoded, nfe_itens_encoded})`

Comment: @JasonSperske I don't think so. I tested with just one object data `nfe_encoded` and it works very well: `requests.put(url2, data=nfe_encoded)`

Comment: @MartijnPieters, does that mean that the assignment doesn't actually have meaning inside the method other than to tell the developer what the set is being utilized for?

Comment: @JasonSperske: it means that the `data` keyword argument is given a `set` value when the method is called. The `requests` *code* cannot handle a `set` value, however.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ahh, thanks.  I was approaching it as though you had to pick ordered method arguments or keyword arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you pass to data should be encoded.  You are encoding the two structures then building an unencoded structure around it.  Try this

```
r = requests.put(url, data=json.dumps([nfe, nfe_itens])
```

Comment: Thanks @cmd, but don't works. There's no exception, but in my Delphi function it's impossible to access the data objects. I get an `Access Violation`

Comment: Look the result of `print json.dumps([nfe, nfe_itens])`: All of the result is through an array: `[{"NaturezaOperacao": "1",...,"CodigoEmpresa": 1}, [{"DescontoUnitario": 1,...,"CodigoProduto": 1}]]` This cause an error.

Comment: @LucasMedeiros how is your delphi is expecting the data to look?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using just one object data parameter with a "sub-object", and then I manage it on my server. I think it is the better way to use more of available features that JSON provides.